# Can and can't update some of database records

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

im having a problem and i really need a help for my problem. I can update some of my records but there're some record that i can't update as well. I already search for solutions but bad luck. I didn't solve my problem. So here's my code

```
 $lanm = $_POST['lastname'];
          $finm = $_POST['firstname'];
          $scho = $_POST['school'];
          $allo = $_POST['allowance'];
          $bday = $_POST['birthday'];
          $grad = $_POST['gradelevel'];
          $fmly = $_POST['family'];
          $favo = $_POST['favoriteSubject'];
          $stat = $_POST['status'];
          $gnd  = $_POST['gender'];
          $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root') or die ('Unable to Connect');


      mysql_select_db('bighoop') or die ('Unable to Select a database');
      $query1 = "UPDATE `tbl_students` SET Gender = '$gnd', `Lastname`='$lanm', `Firstname`='$finm', 
      `Birthday`='$bday', `Grade_level`='$grad', `Family_size`='$fmly', 
      `Fav_subject`='$favo', tbl_students.School_id='$scho', tbl_students.Status ='$stat',
       tbl_students.Allowance_Id = '$allo' WHERE tbl_students.Student_id ='".$sid[$x]."';";
```

Comment: Be more specific, which rows will not update? Does the query sometimes work and sometimes not? How does your table look like? What values are in there?

Comment: I think the issue may be because you are not escaping the data. Try escaping the data first.

Comment: since i have many rows, i don't know which is working and which is not. The values are strings.

Comment: You are probably sql-injecting yourself. Problems with the `O'Brien` family, etc. You should really switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements.

Comment: question is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

Be specific about the row which is not updating and the row which is updating. Then only we can identify the problem